# Let $G$ act faithfully & transitively on $A$, and $N\unlhd G$ s.t $N$ acts regularly on $A$. Show $G_\alpha$ embeds as a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups, automorphism-group

Question:

Let $G$ be a finite group acting faithfully and transitively on a set $A$.  Assume there exists $N\trianglelefteq G$ such that $N$ acts regularly on $A$.  Prove $G_\alpha$ embeds as a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(N)$, where $\alpha\in A$.

Thoughts:

As $N$ acts regularly on $A$, we have that $G=G_\alpha N$ and $G_\alpha\cap N=1$ for all $\alpha\in A$.  Since $G$ acts faithfully and transitively on $A$, we know that there is a bijection, $\phi$, from $G$ to the symmetric group.  Since $N\trianglelefteq G$, we have that $G/N$ acts faithfully on $A$ where $(gN)\cdot\alpha=g\cdot\alpha$.  From here, I am not sure if I should try and do something with the orbit-stabilizer theorem, or if there is a better approach to sort of tie everything together.

Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

EDIT: I've seen the solution provided by Jun Koizumi, but I am more interested to see how one could prove the statement given the definition of regular action rather than passing onto the stronger statement.

Answer (score 3):

I will prove a slightly stronger statement:

**Theorem.**
Let $G$ be a group acting faithfully on a set $A$.
Assume that there exists a normal subgroup $N\unlhd G$ such that $N$ acts transitively on $A$.
Then for each $\alpha \in A$, its stabilizer $G_\alpha$ embeds as a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(N)$.

**Proof.**
Define a homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to \operatorname{Aut}(N)$ by
$$
\varphi(g)=(h\mapsto ghg^{-1}).
$$
Let $\alpha\in A$.
I will prove that $\varphi|_{G_\alpha}$ is injective.
Suppose that $g\in G_\alpha$ is in the kernel of $\varphi$, i.e. $h=ghg^{-1}$ holds for any $h\in N$.
Then we have
$$
h\cdot \alpha = g\cdot (h\cdot (g^{-1}\cdot \alpha)) = g\cdot(h\cdot \alpha),
$$
so $g$ fixes $h\cdot \alpha$ as well.
Since the action of $N$ on $A$ is transitive, we get $g\cdot \beta=\beta$ for all $\beta\in A$.
Since the action of $G$ on $A$ is faithful, we get $g=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I have seen a proof of this statement before.  I suppose I was getting tripped up on how to prove using definition of regular action, so I was really hoping to see that.  But, thank you, I do really appreciate this!